# Display data from Mat / cv::Mat for an image in matrix form (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I dealing with school project now and I hopping to display the pixels value for an random image in matrix form. Below is the code I use to determine the number rows and column but I hope to get all the pixel value by columns and rows. Sorry for the bad explanation with less information cause I just getting familiar with opencv but I hope someone can really help me on this.

Thanks

```
if( src.empty() )
{ cout << "No input picture" << endl;return -1; }

namedWindow( "Original image", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO );
    imshow( "Original image", src);


cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
namedWindow( "Gray image", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO );  
    imshow( "Gray image", gray );

Canny( gray, edge, 50, 150, 3);
edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);
    namedWindow("edge", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO );
    imshow("edge", draw);   

int rows = draw.rows;
int cols = draw.cols;

for(int y=0; y<rows; ++y) for(int x=0; x<cols; ++x) std::cout << "("<<x<<","<<y<<") = " << draw.at<unsigned char>(y,x) << std::endl;

//cout<< edge <<endl;   
cout<<"Number of rows:  "<<draw.rows<<endl;
cout<<"Number of columns:  "<<draw.cols<<endl;  


//cout << src << endl;


waitKey(0);                                       
    return 0;
```

Comment: Try to use `cout << src;`

Comment: @incBrain Thanks for the reply. Accurately I tried that but the result show a bit messy cause I complier and run the code by using terminal only. Is that anyway to display in more organize way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *display in more organize way*, but you can iterate over all rows and cols and do whatever you want ;)

Comment: `for(int y=0; y<rows; ++y) for(int x=0; x<cols; ++x) std::cout << "("<<x<<","<<y<<") = " << src.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) << std::endl;`

Comment: instead of `if( !src.data )` I would use `if(src.empty())` should be the same result but better readability

Comment: For clarification, I want to inspect the pixels value and show in the form of matrix like what the picture shows inside the link below: 

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Comment: @incBrain but just using terminal to run the code, the result only show numbers without organize in rows and columns.

Comment: @Micka Thanks micka, I will try it out now.

Comment: what's your image size? for typical resolutions you won't fit an image row in one terminal row...

Comment: @Micka using the code above the number of rows and column both is 225.

Comment: probably won't fit in the terminal rows/columns ;) my sample code prints one pixel value per terminal line.

Comment: @Micka In understood now. any suggest program that can use to make a demo on that? Btw I already tried your sample code, one of the result shows as below:

(183,222) = [76, 86, 193]

From what I understand is the (183,222) represent the column and rows, but how about the 76, 86, 193?

Comment: your color image has 3 channels. first value is the blue channel intensity. second is green channel, third is red channel. pixel intensities (each channel) range between 0 and 255 for that kind of images.

Comment: @Micka Ya, I guess I asked a stupid question before I really study on it. So let say that I turn my image to edges using Canny( src, edge, 50, 150, 3); <<example. Can I use the same method to determine the pixel values?

Comment: no because the canny edge image will have only one channel. you'll have to change to: `src.at<unsigned char>(y,x)` because cv::Vec3b is 3 byte values (24 bit from 3 channels) and `unsigned char` is a single byte (1 channel)

Comment: @Micka,  I edited my code as show as above but I fail to get the result.

Comment: remove the line edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);

Comment: The result still the same although I remove the line edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);

Comment: It show part of the result like this:

(218,224) = 
(219,224) = �
(220,224) = �